Linking against (self built) OpenCV+Contribs for Ubuntu 22.04
We have a program that we build for Windows and Ubuntu 20.04 right now. It depends on OpenCV (version 4.2 for Ubuntu 20.04). The program is built via CMake in a automated Gitlab CI/CD with Docker runners. The CI/CD runners are using a custom made docker image which is based on Ubuntu with a locally build OpenCV+contribs.
Now we want to build a version for Ubuntu 22.04 too. After figuring out all dependencies we got a problem we the vanilla OpenCV version in Ubuntu 22.04. We use a docker image with OpenCV 4.5.4 locally build and link our program against it. After building we build a .deb file from it, like for Ubuntu 20.04. But when trying to start the binary on Ubuntu 22.04 it fails to load the OpenCV libs because under Ubuntu 22.04 they are named 4.5d instead of 4.5.
I'm not that deep into linking and libraries and whonder how to solve this problem. I would prefer to modify the OpenCV builds in my docker image to match onto the naming scheme of Ubuntu 22.04.
I tried renaming the opencv libs in the docker image after building them. That was a more or less desperate attempt that failed as expected.

If you're building against a custom build of OpenCV, why do you care how the standard packages are named? You're going to need to ship that custom build of OpenCV as well, otherwise what's the point of the whole excercise?
